# Marmalade or Adobe AIR to embedded in Android/ios codes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine, marmalade

My team has a project which has native app features 
and some games within.

At first , I thought Unity3D is a good choice for us,
but I found that the battery drain is a problem.
Also,it's hard to refer to a native features of Android/ios in unity.
I want it to run the native part quietly and and to run the game part fast.

So is it possible that I develop this app basically 
in Android/ios using Java or Objective-c with Marmalade or Adobe AIR？

Answer (score 0):

You can not mix and match here. You need to either go full Cross platform or full native.

I follow this rule of thumb,

> Whenever you are in doubt always go native.

You can have extensions and plugins to support native functionality in Adobe Air, Unity3D or marmalade. So there wouldn't be any issue with it. Since there's some game content, you should choose a game engine such as Unity3D to do this.

In theory each one of these options are capable of achieving this. It's upto you to find pros and cons of each.